# Is Kafka able to have a dynamic number of consumers?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, messaging, apache-kafka

We are looking for a new messaging platform, and have narrowed our choices down to RabbitMQ or Kafka.

Right now, I am leaning toward Kafka, but I have some doubts that it is a good choice given one of our requirements.

We need to have a queue that is consumed by an unknown number of consumers.  That is, we need to dynamically add and remove consumers as "workers" come online to do the processing.  Also, workers may drop off at any time.

So for example, we may start a queue that has no consumers at all, and then the number of consumers may grow to 30.  Later it may grow to 5000 or more, and then drop back off to 3.

We do not care about message ordering for this particular use case.  Is Kafka a good fit for this?

Also, we were planning on maintaining a pool of consumer threads so that the workers could grab a single message and process it.  So there may be 100 consumers in the pool and only 20 workers.  Is it possible that we end up with messages in the other 80 consumers which are not utilized in the workers due to message send buffering?  In other words, does Kafka pre-deliver messages to consumers before they are requested like some messaging systems do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kafka can definitely match your requirements. You can have many-to-many producers/consumers. If all your consumers are within the same consumer group all messages will be distributed evenly between all consumers. It is not a problem also if you shut down / add new consumers, kafka will manage all automatically for you.

To your last question - kafka consumers are pull-based, so it is consumer responsibility to check if there are some messages to process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is very helpful.  You say that all messages will be distributed evenly between all consumers, but what if one of the consumers is really slow at processing and others are fast?  Will the queue be held up waiting for the slow one?  This would not be ideal.

Comment: @WickedElephant Yes, in that case it is possible, that the slow consumer makes the consumer group slow. But it is in the case of very few partitions (for example 1 or 2). Actually it is not the messages that will be distributed evenly between consumers, but kafka partitions. So if you have enough partitions all consumers will be working fast.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. After giving this some consideration, I do not know if this will work for us because we have no way of knowing how many partitions we will need.  And we can't add/remove partitions on the fly as needed in kafka.  We would end up in situations where we have messages in partitions that do not have consumers.  I realize this is an odd use case, but it seems kafka may not be a good fit for this one.